# Refreshing UI activity (Screen) from background thread (Timer task)

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-activity, timer

I am new bee to android world and need urgent help.

I have application with background thread that pulls data from server and pushes outbox data to the server at regular interval.
If new message is received and at that time user has an UI activity open  (say Inbox screen)
it should get refreshed, i mean new messages should be populated on the screen at the same time.

Which screen user is viewing i am not sure it can be inbox or outbox.

Sorry for that long description

Answer (score -1):

The following code should help you fine.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
  public void run() {
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your code here            
    }
  });
  }
};


Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, splashTime);
```